# How to make connection using cable USB to RJ45 serial connection in android

Tags: android, serial-port, usb, usbserial

I have to make connection between machine and device via Rs232 protocol but I am facing problem in connection. When we are making connection from cable we didn't get any status like cable is connected or not, also not getting any alert popup for usbhost

I have checked with RS232 converter adapter and Its working. But I have to make it work in one end with android USB port and another end with RJ45 port in it.
[image]
My Question is how to make connection with the hardware which supports RS232 protocol. I have tried many examples but didn't work for me.

Comment: As your question content is, it is not clear that you said why / what you want to do, at what point, what kind of information / notification you want, what is the problem. Please add them.

Comment: I have updated my question please help me and let me know if you required more information. @kunif

Answer (score 1):

The protocol is established only when there is a target device for connection.
Even if only photos of USB to RJ45 cable are presented, nothing can be answered.

First of all, is the driver and information of this cable device installed to android?
If it is not done, nothing will work.
These information may be helpful.
[USB host overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host) , 
[Install OEM USB drivers](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb)

Then, what you want to know is the pin assignment of RJ45?
There seems to be no standard for RS232C pin assignment of RJ45, so you will only have to ask cable manufacturer / retailer for accurate information.
I think that there is a possibility that someone who knows saw this article then tell you that, but it would be better not to expect too much.

However, since Cisco systems seems to have a large share, you may find pin assign based on this information.
[Cabling Guide for Console and AUX Ports](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/routers/7000-series-routers/12223-14.html)

Finally and again, the protocol depends on the specification of the target device and the software.
If such information is not presented, nobody can answer.

In addition,
Does the MicroB to USB-A conversion cable support the host function?